# I have a package I can't seem to uninstall (Debian)

Tags: debian, software-installation, uninstall

So I am using the [Pine Phone](https://www.pine64.org/pinephone/) running Debian and it comes preinstalled with an app [Chatty](https://source.puri.sm/Librem5/chatty) which does SMS but isn't able to do MMS. A community member had their own branch which runs MMS so I went and built that from source and uninstalled the original Chatty through `apt` but it seems like now I am not able to update this from either building from source or through apt. Either way when I look at my app version it shows v0.1.12 and the current version is v0.4.

Now my issue is I know Chatty isn't installed through apt because when I run `sudo apt remove chatty` I get back `not installed, so not removed` and when I go in and uninstall through version built from source with `ninja uninstall -C build` that runs just fine but Chatty is still there. My current theory is a few months back I made the clone for the MMS branch and built it from source but when trying to pull more recent code it didn't work so I deleted that directory without uninstalling it so that is the current install.

Is there any way to delete this app? When I installed through apt or build from source they both seem to install but they still open the older version. So if not a way to uninstall is there a way to make it launch a specific version? Because in theory I have just built the most recent version of the program but it doesn't launch that version.